# Jest error: Your test suite must contain at least one test

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

i know that this question has already been asked elswhere, but in my case, i followed the jest best practice video from mickael guay ([click to view](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Vc6Xw8FMpg&ab_channel=MichaelGuay))

But unfortunately i get the jest error,  ***Your test suite must contain at least one test***
But one test is passing just after that.

[image]

here's my code:
[...]

```
const mockResponse = {
  json: jest.fn(),
  status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
} as unknown as Response<any, Record<string, any>>;

describe('UsersController', () => {
  let usersController: UsersController;
  let usersService: UsersService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        { provide: getModelToken(User.name), useValue: jest.fn() },
        { provide: getModelToken(Role.name), useValue: jest.fn() },
      ],
    }).compile();

    usersController = moduleRef.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
    usersService = moduleRef.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('findOneById', () => {
    describe('when findOneById is called', () => {
      beforeEach(async () => {
        const user: Partial<User> & Response =
          await usersController.findOneById(mockResponse, userStub().userId);
        console.log('user', user);
      });

      it('then it should call usersService', () => {
        expect(usersService.findOneById).toBeCalledWith(userStub().userId);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I think maybe it's because i have a describe() nested in a describe(), that makes the first describe() waiting also for a test ?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Remove any wrapping `describe` without a direct `it`, they are not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** figure it out when i realized that i had another old .spec file hidden in another folder. removing it solved the issue.